# High GC time for simple mapreduce problem

Tags: performance, julia

I have simulation program written in Julia that does something equivalent to this as a part of its main loop:

```
# Some fake data
M = [randn(100,100) for m=1:100, n=1:100]
W = randn(100,100)
work = zip(W,M)
result = mapreduce(x -> x[1]*x[2], +,work)
```

In other words, a simple sum of weighted matrices. Timing the above code yields

```
0.691084 seconds (79.03 k allocations: 1.493 GiB, 70.59% gc time, 2.79% compilation time)
```

I am surprised about the large number of memory allocations, as this problem should be possible to do in-place. To see if it was my use of mapreduce that was wrong I also tested the following equivalent implementation:

```
@time begin
    res = zeros(100,100)
    for m=1:100
        for n=1:100
            res += W[m,n] * M[m,n]
        end
    end
end
```

which gave

```
0.442521 seconds (50.00 k allocations: 1.491 GiB, 70.81% gc time)
```

So, if I wrote this in C++ or Fortran it would be simple to do all of this in-place. Is this impossible in Julia? Or am I missing something here...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to do it in place like this:

```
function ws(W, M)
    res = zeros(100,100)
    for m=1:100
        for n=1:100
            @. res += W[m,n] * M[m, n]
        end
    end
    return res
end
```

and the timing is:

```
julia> @time ws(W, M);
  0.100328 seconds (2 allocations: 78.172 KiB)
```

Note that in order to perform this operation in-place I used broadcasting (I could also use loops, but it would be the same).

The problem with your code is that in line:

```
res += W[m,n] * M[m,n]
```

You get two allocations:

1. When you do multiplication `W[m,n] * M[m,n]` a new matrix is allocated.
2. When you do addition `res += ...` again a matrix is allocated

By using broadcasting with `@.` you perform an in-place operation, see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/mathematical-operations/#man-dot-operators for more explanations.

Additionally note that I have wrapped the code inside a function. If you do not do it then access both `W` and `M` is type unstable which also causes allocations, see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#Avoid-global-variables.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I notice that if I write my inner loop as : `res .+= W[m,n] .* M[m, n]` I get the same result. Can I infer that this is exactly what this macro (@.) does? (If so - it is definitely a cleaner way to express this technique).

Comment: Yes `@.` is applying `.` to every function call in the expression. In this case it is `+` and `+=` operations.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to add something to Bogumił's answer.  The missing broadcast is the main problem, but in addition, the loop and the `mapreduce` variant differ in a fundamental semantic way.

The purpose of `mapreduce` is to reduce by an associative operation with identity element `init` in an unspecified order.  This in particular also includes the (theoretical) option of running parts in parallel and doesn't really play well with mutation.  From the docs:

> The associativity of the reduction is implementation-dependent. Additionally, some implementations may reuse the return value of `f` for elements that appear multiple times in `itr`. Use `mapfoldl` or
> `mapfoldr` instead for guaranteed left or right associativity and invocation of `f` for every value.

and

> It is unspecified whether `init` is used for non-empty collections.

What the loop variant really corresponds to is a fold, which has a well-defined order and initial (not necessarily identity) element and can thus use an in-place reduction operator:

> Like `reduce`, but with guaranteed left associativity. If provided, the keyword argument `init` will be used exactly once.

```
julia> @benchmark foldl((acc, (m, w)) -> (@. acc += m * w), $work; init=$(zero(W)))
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 45 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  109.967 ms … 118.251 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 0.00%
 Time  (median):     112.639 ms               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   112.862 ms ±   1.154 ms  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.00% ± 0.00%

                  ▄▃█ ▁▄▃                                        
  ▄▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▄███▆███▄▁▄▁▁▄▁▁▄▁▁▁▁▁▄▁▁▄▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▄ ▁
  110 ms           Histogram: frequency by time          118 ms <

 Memory estimate: 0 bytes, allocs estimate: 0.

julia> @benchmark mapreduce(Base.splat(*), +, $work)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 12 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  403.100 ms … 458.882 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 4.53% … 3.89%
 Time  (median):     445.058 ms               ┊ GC (median):    4.04%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   440.042 ms ±  16.792 ms  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  4.21% ± 0.92%

  ▁           ▁                 ▁   ▁      ▁ ▁    ▁▁▁     █   ▁  
  █▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁█▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁█▁▁▁█▁▁▁▁▁▁█▁█▁▁▁▁███▁▁▁▁▁█▁▁▁█ ▁
  403 ms           Histogram: frequency by time          459 ms <

 Memory estimate: 1.49 GiB, allocs estimate: 39998.
```

Think of it that way: if you would write the function as a [parallel for loop](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/distributed-computing/) with `(+)` reduction, iteration also would have an unspecified order, and you'd have memory overhead for the necessary copying of the individual results to the accumulating thread.

Thus, there is a trade-off.  In your example, allocation/copying dominates.  In other cases, the the mapped operation might dominate, and parallel reduction (with unspecified order, but copying overhead) be worth it.

Comment: A very good comment.

Comment: I think you want `init=zero(W)`.